# How to link foreign key between @Entity in spring boot data jpa

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Technologies:

1. mysql 8
2. spring-boot-starter-parent 2.3.3.RELEASE
3. With spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

Error:

```
nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: **could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null];** 
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`emr`.`user_detail`, CONSTRAINT `user_detail_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `facility` (`id`))
```

DDLs:

```sql
create table facility
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(60),
    address varchar(200)
);
    
create table user_detail
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username varchar(20) not null unique,
    contactNo varchar(12),
    facilityId int unsigned
    foreign key (id) references facility(id)
);
```

Java classes:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name= "user_detail")
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String username;

    @Column (name="contactNo")
    private String contactNo;
        
    @Column (name="facilityId")
    private Integer facilityId;
    
    //getter and setter
}
    
@Entity
@Table(name="facility")
public class Facility {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

Let's say `facility` table has 1 row with `Id=1` and `name='Facility 1'`
I'm trying to insert a row in `user_detail` table for `facilityId=1` but getting error message

As much I understand it is unable to find that `facilityId` is field `id` in `Facility.java` and assuming `null` value which is not permissible in `user_detail.facilityId` column

I'm completely stumped at making code understand that `id` is the Field of foreign key. Tried some combinations of `@JoinColumn` without success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception shows that when you try to save User it saves null as facilityId.

To make this work you need to specify the Facility as another table in User entity (you did it wrong way).

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "user_detail")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String username;
    @Column (name="contactNo")
    private String contactNo;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "facilityId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Facility facility;
    
    //getter and setter
}
```

Based on your requirement you need to specify the relationship. It seems here that the relationship should be one to one so I marked it as such.

Comment: Error is gone but it stored facilityId column as null in database. 1 facility can have many users

Comment: Did you set the Facility object reference while persisting?

Comment: Oh, No, it was direct user details to persist, do I need to externally fetch Facility for that facilityId and set it?

Comment: Yes you need to get the fecility and use setFecility(facilityObj) to set the id for the felicityId column..

Comment: Whether you get the fecility when you do findById ?

Comment: yes i get that Object correctly. but can't I directly feed the facilityId as Integer in User class. i think it will work if I rename id to facilityId in database and Facility.java

Comment: Ahhhh.. Just now saw your query.. instead of referencing the foreign key you referenced the id of the table..  foreign key (id) references facility(id) =>  foreign key (facilityId ) references facility(id)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `@MapsId` [annotation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-derived) here to borrow the identifier from a many-to-one or one-to-one association.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name= "user_detail")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapsId
    private Facility facility;

    //getter and setter
}
```

Comment: SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'facility_id' in 'field list'

Comment: Why do you use the column `facility_id` at all? As I see from your table `user_detail` definition : `foreign key (id) references facility(id)` , the `user_detail.id` is the foreign key to the `facility` table.

Comment: Not using facility_id anywhere , must be internally derived and looking for facility_id